# How to transfer login session from website to react native app using supabase auth and expo router?

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt, expo, supabase

I am trying to create a mobile app onboarding experience that happens on the **web**.

Once the user completes the onboarding and signs in to my web app, I want to transfer them to my mobile app, where they will download it and instead of completing the same onboarding on the react native app, I want them to be automatically signed in.

I assume, I would have to use deeplinks, but I don't know how, what would I have to pass to the deeplink, so that my mobile app could recognise it that *this user has completed their onboarding already and we can sign them in*

I am using supabase and expo with expo router.